# Update Multiple Fields using JQueryUI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've done a lot of research, but I can't quite find a solution to my problem. I pray you are able to help me.

Technology Used:

I'm using JQueryUI to create an autocomplete feature. It works with a basic dataset, but I'm attempting to create the source data as a JSON array of objects locally on the page using a MySQL Query in PHP.

What I'm doing:

In my code, I have four fields and I'm doing autocomplete on the field #first.  What I would like to happen is, upon selecting an item in the autocomplete list, it populates all four fields with data from the source.  Right now nothing is being populated in the autocomplete as I believe my JSON array of objects isn't correctly formatted and the autocomplete call can't read the dataset.

I need to know:

- I have data in the object for each field that is to be populated. Am I creating the array of objects correctly with the multiple items in each object?
- What JQuery I need to write to update the four fields upon item selection in autocomplete
- How do I make the autocomplete work from either of the four fields and still have it update all four fields upon selection and use the same dataset?

My Code:

```
<input type="text" id="first" name="first">

<input type="text" id="last" name="last">

<input type="text" id="email" name="email">

<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">

$( "#first" ).autocomplete({

<?php

    echo 'source: [';

    $nr = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 

        if ($nr == $nrows)  echo '[ {label: "first", value: "'. $row['first'] .'"}, { label: "last", value: "'. $row['last'] .'"}, {label: "email", value: "'. $row['email'] .'"}, { label: "phone", value: "'. $row['phone'] .'"} ]';
        else                echo '[ {label: "first", value: "'. $row['first'] .'"}, { label: "last", value: "'. $row['last'] .'"}, {label: "email", value: "'. $row['email'] .'"}, { label: "phone", value: "'. $row['phone'] .'"} ],';     

        $nr++;
    }                                                                                               
    echo ']';

    ? >

});
```

Comment: Please review Custom Data exmaple: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data Also we will need a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to update your data format so that it returns an Array of Objects of data that Autocomplete can use.

```
[{
  label,
  value
}]
```

This is the basic structure, but you can add your own elements to this.

```
[{
  label,
  value,
  first
  last
  email
  phone
}]
```

The order is not too important. I would advise setting up a stand alone PHP Script that Autocomplete can call to get the data. This is discussed here: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Here is an example with data:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#first").autocomplete({
    source: [{
      label: "Homer Simpson",
      value: "Homer",
      first: "Homer",
      last: "Simpson",
      phone: "(417) 555-1212",
      email: "chunkylover53@aol.com"
    }, {
      label: "Marge Simpson",
      value: "Marge",
      first: "Marge",
      last: "Simpson",
      phone: "(417) 555-1212",
      email: ""
    }, {
      label: "Bart Simpson",
      value: "Bart",
      first: "Bart",
      last: "Simpson",
      phone: "(417) 555-1212",
      email: "c"
    }],
    select: function(e, ui) {
      $("#first").val(ui.item.first);
      $("#last").val(ui.item.last);
      $("#phone").val(ui.item.phone);
      $("#email").val(ui.item.email);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first" name="first">
<input type="text" id="last" name="last">
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
```

In PHP You can create a stand-alone script:

```
<?php
/* -- Connect to SQL -- */
/* -- Perform Query based on $_GET['term'] -- */
$nr = 1;
$results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
  array_push(array(
    "label" => $row['first'] . " " . $row["last"],
    "value" => $row['first'],
    "first" => $row['first'],
    "last" => $row['last'],
    "phone" => $row['phone'],
    "email" => $row['email'],
  ));
}

/*-- Close SQL Connection --*/
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

You can then set the Autocomplete `source` to the URL of that script.